# How to select the 3G

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I am using Moto E with Lollipop 5.1 And I am having this trouble that whenever I am using 3G service, it automatically switches to 2G and i can't able to select 3G (3G selection is not available/showing). How to select the 3G.

Comment: Please check whether  there is any  option for `3G only`? And set it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings>Mobile Network>Network Mode there will be three modes for you GSM only, WCDM only and both. Just select WCDM only option and then you can use 3G.